# How do I deactivate the Shift + Alt hotkey for shifting keyboards in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

While editing Wikipedia I frequently use the Shift + Alt + S hotkey to save the Wikipedia page. Unfortunately, Windows 10 has linked Shift + Alt to switching the keyboard. How do I deactivate the default keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try this:

Type "Advanced Keyboard Settings" into the windows search window (bottom left of screen)
Click on the link
Click on "Language bar options"
Click on "Advanced Key Settings" tab
Make changes as needed here.

This worked for me as of 1/6/2019.  I hope it helps.

Comment: Still works exactly as described, even in Windows 11 at the end of 2021.

Comment: Confirming these settings worked for me on Windows 11 22H2 in July 2023.

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1229224/how-to-avoid-keyboard-layout-automatically-changing-on-windows-10) with screenshots.

"...Go to Control Panel\Clock, Language and Region\Language\Advanced settings\Change Language Bar hotkeys

In the "Advanced Key Settings" tab, select "Between input languages" and click on "Change Key Sequence..."

You can now choose to enable, disable or change the two shortcuts..."

Comment: The screenshots describe how it works with Windows 8 not Windows 10.

Comment: @Christian, these look the same in 8.1 and 10, if accessing via control panel (right-click start button - Control Panel) and not settings.  The only difference, i can see is that 8.1 uses a centered format for the text in the title bar.