# Disable Shortcut in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I use two keyboard layouts and want to be able to switch between them regularly. Ctrl+Shift switches between them, but in some applications I need to use both keys for other shortcuts (e.g. Google Chrome's Ctrl+Shift+N) and the Windows shortcut sometimes interferes. The Win+Space shortcut also switches between them and suits my purposes fine. Is there a way to disable the Ctrl+Shift shortcut in Windows?

Comment: Looks like this has been asked twice in the past for previous versions of Windows: https://superuser.com/questions/109066/how-to-disable-ctrlshift-keyboard-layout-switch-for-the-same-input-language-i?rq=1 https://superuser.com/questions/604790/how-to-disable-ctrlshift-keyboard-layout-switch-in-windows-8?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Microsoft support document suggests you can disable the shortcut:

1. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
2. Double-click Regional and Language Options.
3. Click Keyboards and Languages, and then click Change keyboards.
4. Click Advanced Key Settings, and select Between input languages.
5. Click change Key Sequence.
6. For Switch Keyboard Layout, select Not Assigned.
7. Click OK to close each dialog box.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/967893/input-method-editor-keyboard-shortcut-ctrl-shift-0-switches-the-input