# Change keyboard shortcuts in Win10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

So I came across [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/958901/set-shortcuts-to-change-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10) when trying to change my hotkeys for changing the keyboard layouts.
For some reason Microsoft decided that only the <kbd>left alt</kbd>+<kbd>left shift</kbd> is possible for changing layouts.
Is there a way to make this either side of the keyboard <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> combination?

I've tried going to `Control Panel` -> `Clock, Language and Region` -> `Language` -> `Advanced settings` to maybe set that combination for a single language but it's not one of the options there.

I'm used to changing it from both sides on my work and university computers and it's making me mad.

Answer (score 1):

Set as below , so that you can click left-shift+ctrl to change input layout
[image]

[image]

Comment: yeah but i want to use either combination of <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>. not just the left.

Comment: I configure as the picture shows, then I can use shift+ctrl on the right. Or left shift+ right ctrl

Comment: Please note that I was looking for a custom option, and not one those listed above.