# How to switch keyboard layout from command line?

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, keyboard-layout

You can set Ctrl + Shift + 1 to switch keyboard to English, and set Ctrl + Shift + 2 to switch keyboard to some other language. This can be done in Windows settings ("[Hot keys for input languages](https://superuser.com/questions/958901/set-shortcuts-to-change-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10)").

Now, my keyboard has a number of additional keys, which are free to bind to user's actions. Keyboard software allows you to specify an application (command line) to execute when such additional key is pressed.

So, I want to assign keyboard switching to these additional keyboard keys. Is there a way to do this via command line or powershell?

P.S. I could write an app to switch keyboard, but I would rather prefer to use build-in features only.

Comment: This? [Configure international settings by using Windows PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-international-settings-in-windows#configure-international-settings-by-using-windows-powershell)

Comment: @CaldeiraG Unless I am missing something - no, it is not it. Those are internationalization SETTINGS, like UI lang, country (location), number formats, lang for ANSI, etc. It does not have anything related to input profiles (e.g. Lang ID + Keyboard ID).

Comment: @harrymc Sorry, did you read question that you have linked to? Answers are answering a different question. They are all about changing SETTINGS (e.g. like UI lang, country (location), number formats, lang for ANSI, etc). There is nothing about actual input profile. For example, accepted answer does nothing to change input method (as displayed by language bar). Not to mention that linked question is about Windows XP and Windows 7.