# How create a short way to convert the keyboard into specific language?

Tags: keyboard, language

I'm using many languages on my PC, and if I want to move from one language to another, I have to click <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> for many times until I get the language that I want. Needless to say that it's not convenient at all to work in such a way.

Is there a way to make it shorter? For example, to definite some specific keys to change to a specific language by one action (rather than many, as in my case).

Comment: This question was [already answered](https://superuser.com/a/1368543/1178863) for windows 10. Answer should work, unless needed setting was moved again in last two years.

Comment: Could it be that I have a different version of Windows 10? I don't have "*Clock, Language, and Region*", but I have "clock and region" (only). Also, I don't have the option "change input methods" as I commented below. Thank you

Comment: First answer is for older version. Others are for newer versions. [Try this](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=%21ALH91gryZd6TQ4g&id=8FD4EC3161ABA67A%213423&cid=8FD4EC3161ABA67A)

Comment: Yes, I followed all the steps, changed the language to control +0, but it still doesn't work. What may be the reason?

Comment: As said in the answer: These hotkeys are quite buggy since 2012 or so. They may disappear (the setting is cleared or simply not working) after a windows update, after an RDP session, after logout/login, or even without any obvious reason.  You might want to check if settings are still there. If they are missing, there's one well-known [workaround](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-desktop-winpc/language-hotkeys-removed-by-itself-windows-10/6dab4f93-170c-4e4c-8eab-4b73eb6b1643?messageId=38dbe475-e759-42a6-9c25-cb48a49c62b2), that usually helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem faced by people using multiple input languages in Windows PC and it's really cumbersome to switch between many languages pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>. We can assign particular keys for particular languages and make this process easy.

- Go to `Control Panel`.
- Under Clock, Language and Region, Select `Change input methods`:

[image]

- Go to `Advanced Settings`:

[image]

- Click `Change language bar hot keys`:

[image]

- Select a language and click `Change Key Sequence`:

[image]

- From the menu that pops up, "Mark" the 'Enable key sequence' and select a key sequence from the dropdown menu. I am selecting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> combination for that particular language and press OK:

[image]

- Click `Apply` and that particular hotkey combination will be set for the language that you selected:

[image]

Now, whenever you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, you will switch directly to that input language.

That's it. I hope this helps. Do let me know how it does :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your attempt to help. It seems a very good guide but unfortunately, I have windows 10 (home) and I have a different control panel than yours. I have "clock and region" (only!) while you have "clock language and region". Also, I don't have the option "change input methods". :(  If you know how to adjust your instruction to my system it'll be great.

Comment: My system is also windows 10 home and everything I have written is there. Can you provide a screenshot of your control panel?

Comment: My version is 1909. Could it be that we have different versions? Here is a screenshot of it: https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=503010497944

Comment: Yeah, I am running on 1709 but that shouldn't make a huge difference. Btw, there's no screenshot in that link and clicking that link redirects to photobox.co.uk :|

Do one thing, search for 'Language' in the search box in control panel and you should see that language option.

Comment: Thank you. then check here: https://ibb.co/Rb96PDW Do you see?

Comment: I've checked in newer version of windows 10 and seems like they have made that option of language toggle hotkey obsolete :|