# Set shortcut switching multiple language keyboard

Tags: windows, windows-10

I've read [Set shortcuts to change keyboard layout in Windows 10? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/958901/set-shortcuts-to-change-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10)

There're there language keyboards on my PC, I expected switching language like :

```
windows + 1 : english
windows + 2 : japanese
windows + 3 : chinese
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below steps to change the hotkeys for keyboard layouts:

1. Hold the Windows key and press I to open Windows Settings. Now head over to the Devices setting。
2. On the left pane of devices, click on the Typing option. Now scroll down and click on the Advanced Keyboard Settings option.
3. In advanced keyboard settings, click on the Input language hotkeys link。
4. Here you can set shortcut keys for any of the languages that you want. Select the language and click on the Change Key Sequence button.

   Note: You can also change the default shortcut for "Between input languages".

[image]

5. Tick on the Enable Key Sequence and choose the shortcut keys below. Then press the Ok button for both opened windows to apply the changes.

[image]