# How to disable Ctrl+Shift keyboard layout switch (for the same input language) in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

This Question was asked before [here](https://superuser.com/q/109066/712699), I am wondering how to do this under Windows 10.
The proposed solution is not feasible for windows 10 since the decribed path does not exist.

In Windows 10, when there are two or more keyboard layouts for the same input language, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> switches the keyboard layout. Where can this be disabled or changed to another keystroke combination?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The new path to this configuration :

- Open PC Settings
- Go to *Time & language*
- Click *Region & Language*
- Click *Advanced keyboard settings*
- Click *Language bar options*
- Go to the *Advanced Key Settings* tab
- Click *Change key sequence...*
- Set one or two of the "Not assigned" options
- Click OK

Comment: NB: It might be impossible to disable the Win+Spacebar to switch between keyboard languages. But at least with that hotkey you will see the keyboard language menu pop out. It *IS* also impossible to disable the chinese IME hotkey (Ctrl+Spacebar), or at least that does not get stored when you press [OK].

Comment: Btw, you can also skip the first steps: Win+i -> search for "language bar".

Answer (score 16):

More recent versions of Windows 10 no longer have the Regional & Language Settings dialog, and the Language Bar Options have been moved to the Advanced Keyboard Settings page.

Now just search for "Language bar" from the Windows search tool and you'll get to an "Advanced keyboard settings" page, then click on "Language bar options" and there you are.

Answer (score 11):

On Windows 10 1809 (August 2019):

Full route:

1. `Settings App` (start menu -> cog icon)
2. `Time and language`
3. `Language` (sidebar)
4. `Spelling typing and keyboard settings` (Under `Related Settings`, Blue text)
5. `Advanced keyboard settings`
6. `Language bar options`
7. `Advanced key settings` (tab)
8. Select, in the `Hotkeys for input languages` group box, in the list view, the row `Between input languages`
9. Click `Change Key Sequence` button
10. Set both radio buttons to `Not Assigned`

Alternative:

1. Search for `Typing settings` on the start menu
2. Go to step 5

The path to access these settings is likely to change on future releases.

Answer (score 3):

Windows 10 and Windows 11:

1. Press Windows+R (run)
2. "C:\Windows\system32\rundll32.exe" Shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL input.dll,,{C07337D3-DB2C-4D0B-9A93-B722A6C106E2}
3. Go to the Advanced Key Settings tab
4. Click Change Key Sequence button
5. Set both radio buttons to Not Assigned

Answer (score 0):

On my system (Windows 10 Pro 22H2), the solution is a bit different than the one provided by the accepted answer. Go to:

*Settings > Time & Language > Language > Keyboard > Input language hot keys*

then select *Between input languages* from the list, and click on *Change Key Sequence*. Finally, select both *Not Assigned* options, and click *OK*.