# Windows change language changing shortcut via bat or powershell file

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, powershell, batch-file

I am in need of a bat or powershell command to change the language switching shortcut in Windows (for example from `Caps Lock` to `Left Shift + Left Alt`. Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: take a look at AutoHotKey. it does macro stuff AND can remap keys fairly easily.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey So I would need to deploy AutoHotKey on other machines previously to using some script? What is the purpose then, if it is less time consuming to change the shortcut manually?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Ctrl+Shift keyboard layout switch (for the same input language) in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/109066/how-to-disable-ctrlshift-keyboard-layout-switch-for-the-same-input-language-i)

Comment: @ymdred16 - AHK can be compiled. you are correct that you would need to distribute that exe file, tho. it looks like `JosefZ` has a better idea for your situation. good luck! [*grin*]

Comment: @JosefZ Yeah. Have found what I need in answers [down below](https://superuser.com/a/813818/1036040), thanks for the link. Should I delete the question or answer it myself? That question in the link you provided is not actually about what I needed.

Comment: Could adjust localization using an xml file. I have something that does keyboards here: https://github.com/mdvthu/keyboardswitch

Answer (score 0):

After looking into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63788748/2552903) (and some others), this PowerShell snippet worked for me:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$wshell.SendKeys("%+()")
```

It sends `Alt` + `Shift`.