# Which key combination makes this popup appear?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-11, keyboard-layout, anydesk

I access a notebook remotely using AnyDesk.  Often, I press some key combination that switches my keyboard layout to a different one, but I don't know which combination it is.  When it happens, this popup appears briefly:

[image: keyboard layout change popup]

I know it states the shortcut "Windows + Spacebar" should be used, but I'm sure that's not what I press.

Comment: Maybe Left Alt + Shift?

Comment: Should definitely be win+space. left alt+shift and left ctrl+shift will only switch without popup.

Comment: @LPChip ctrl+shift does give you the popup? For me there is no popup for any of the 3 conbinations

Comment: no, win+space should give the popup. The other two don't. But only if you have more than one keyboard layouts or languages installed.

Comment: That's it!  Ctrl+shift switches the keyboard and SOMETIMES shows a slightly different popup than the one I posted.  The popup appears if I press ctrl and tap shift, while still keeping ctrl pressed.

Comment: One more thing Microsoft changed between Windows 10 and 11. :P

Comment: Please add it as an answer, so I can check it as the correct one.  Thank you very much!  I wonder if there's a way to turn it off.  (yes, there's a way:  https://superuser.com/questions/109066/how-to-disable-ctrlshift-keyboard-layout-switch-for-the-same-input-language-i/1694869#1694869)

Comment: Oh! If you keep Control pressed. (In that case, it would show for win+space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 keyboard shortcuts when it comes to changing the input language or keyboard layout.

They are:

- <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> : change keyboard layout
- <kbd>left alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> : change keyboard language
- <kbd>left ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd> : change keyboard layout (within the selected language)

In Windows 10 only the first would give you a popup, but our comment exchange explained that Windows 11 now also gives a popup for the 3rd one.

Comment: By the way, there's a way to disable those shortcuts:  https://superuser.com/questions/109066/how-to-disable-ctrlshift-keyboard-layout-switch-for-the-same-input-language-i/1694869#1694869

Comment: The solution provided on the link works.  I disabled the shortcut on my notebook.